# accessing data on a Model's associated Model to perform validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

  validates :email, :email => { :message => "Must be a valid email." }, :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@#{Regexp.quote(school.email_domain)}\z/i }

end
```

I want to be able to validate that on create a user's email matches their school's email domain. I am creating users by:

```
@school.users.create(params[:user])
```

Error thrown :

```
undefined local variable or method `school' for #<Class:0x007f8aaabb0df0>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And whats the question? Is that not working currently?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `school' for #<Class:0x007f8aaabb0df0>

Comment: try using `:school` instead of `school`?

Comment: Its because `school` is an instance method, but its being called within the class context. See my proposed answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to call the `#school` method within the context of your *class* instead of within an *instance* of your class, and `#school` is an instance method.

To call instance methods when constructing your validation format Regexp, you can provide a [lambda](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) as the `:with` option, as follows:

```
validates :email,
  :message => "Must be a valid email",
  :format => { :with => lambda {|user| /\A[\w+\-.]+@#{Regexp.quote(user.school.email_domain)}\z/i } }
```

This lambda will be invoked on your model instance, allowing you to call methods on your `User` instance such as `#school`. See the documentation for [`validates_format_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org) for more details.

Comment: Awesome Stuart! Got to take a closer look at lambdas!

Comment: See this article for a great writeup: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/